# How do I output only the last form submission in for a form. Using React and javascript here. Thank you

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, typescript, frontend

Currently, I have a form on a page. I wish to display the latest form submission below the form, but it will display all the form submissions till date. I am wondering how to approach this issue.

Below is the code for the Form component if it helps.

*

```
export default function TourneyForm() {
  const [hallname, setHallName] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [matricnumber, setMatricNumber] = useState("");
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(0);
  const [sport, setSport] = useState("");
  const [brackettype, setBracketType] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post(TOURNEY_URL, {
        hallname: hallname,
        name: name,
        matricnumber: matricnumber,
        players: players,
        sport: sport,
        brackettype: brackettype,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    setHallName('')
    setName('')
    setMatricNumber('')
    setPlayers(0)
    setSport('')
    setBracketType('')
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group row py-4">
          <div className="col"></div>
          <label className="col-1" htmlFor="hallname">
            Hall Name
          </label>
          <div className="col-3">
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              id="hallname"
              value={hallname}
              onChange={(e) => setHallName(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option selected>Name of Hall/RC</option>
              <option value="Temasek Hall">Temasek Hall</option>
              <option value="Eusoff Hall">Eusoff Hall</option>
              <option value="KEVII Hall">KEVII Hall</option>
              <option value="Kent Ridge Hall">Kent Ridge Hall</option>
              <option value="Sheares Hall">Sheares Hall</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="col"></div>
        </div>
);}
```

- 

Below is the code for the page where I call the Form component and try to display the latest submission below

*

```
export default function CreateTourney() {
  const[data, setData] = useState([])
  axios.get(url)
  .then (function (response) {
    setData(response.data)
  });
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col"></div>
        <span className="col-5 text-center fs-5 py-3">
          Fill in and submit this form to create a new tournament bracket! Click "See all tournaments" to find
          your newly created tournament.
          <br /><br />
          Note: One student number can only be registered for one tournament.
        </span>
        <div className="col"></div>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <TourneyForm />
      
      {data.filter(element.data == )}
        {data.map((element) => <TourneyIndivListing data={element} />)}
      
    </>
    
  )
}
```

- 

I have no idea how to approach this issue. I tried several methods, such as using data filter, or using an if else statement to see if the input value is same as the latest logged value. However, I have no idea what to pass in as the argument and I keep getting errors.. Hope I can receive tips on how to tackle this issue. Thank you so much.

This is the frontend render of the website

[image]

This is an example of the backend database.

[image]

Please let me know if you guys require any extra information. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please replace the images of code with a text-based [mcve]

Comment: @evolutionxbox is this better for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your issue, you would like to display your form with the latest submission right below. Submitting a new form would reset the inputs and update the latest submission displayed below.

As I understand your needs, you have two possibilities.

1. Only recover the last submission from your database if you only need to display that last one and not all of them. This way, you could gain some performance time especially if you have lot of submissions.
   In this case, you need to update your backend code to only recover the last submission. For SQL cases, it will looks something like this:

   SELECT * FROM submisions ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1

Then you should update your CreateTourney component to handle single submissions and not an array of submissions:

```
{data && 
    <TourneyIndivListing data={data} />
}
```

I would also put your axios call in a function, let's call it "fetchSubmission" and call it on component mount using useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetchSubmission()
}, [])
```

Then, add the fetchSubmission() function to your TourneyForm:

```
<TourneyForm fetchSubmission={fetchSubmission}/>
```

You should now call the fetchSubmission function from TourneyForm component in your axios call back so it will refresh your last submission every time a new one is created.

2. Recover all the submissions, ordered by created_date DESC from your backend:

   SELECT * FROM submisions ORDER BY created_at DESC

Then add a condition in your CreateTourney component to display either all submission or the last one.

```
{showAll ?
   data.map((element, index) => ( <TourneyIndivListing key={index} data={element} fetchSubmission={fetchSubmission}/>)
:
<TourneyIndivListing data={data[0]} fetchSubmission={fetchSubmission}/>
}
```

Hope this can help you